# Number of $(x,y,z)$ that have the following property

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $S$ be the set $\{1,2,3,...,19\}$. For $a,b \in S$, define $a\succ b$ to mean that either $0 < a - b \leq 9$ or $b - a > 9$. How
>   many ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ of elements of $S$ have the property
>   that $x \succ y$, $y \succ z$, and $z \succ x$.

The answer is $855=3(9^2+..+1^2)$ from someone. I see that $a-b$ can be interpreted as the distance between $a$ and $b$, however, what should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Arrange the $19$ numbers in order on a circle. What does $x\succ y$ geometrically mean (Take a specific $x$ and see where $y$ satifies)? Try to use complementary counting next after you see what the problem is equivalent to geometrically.